# How to use a for loop inside a Django conditional?

Tags: python, django

Basically if there is a certain GET parameter in the url (in this case "latest") I want to slice the object list by a different number than the usual. But doing this:

```
    {% if 'latest' in request.GET %}
        {% for object in object_list|slice:"22" %}
    {% else %}
        {% for object in object_list|slice:"10" %}
    {% endif %}

         // blah blah

    {% endfor %}
```

causes a syntax error since Django expects a closing `endfor` instead of the else. Is there any way to use for loops inside conditionals?

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a body in your for loop.

```
{% if 'latest' in request.GET %}
    {% for object in object_list|slice:"22" %} {{ object }} {% endfor %}
{% else %}
    {% for object in object_list|slice:"10" %} {{ object }} {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Without it, you're saying the equivalent of the following Python code:

```
if 'latest' in request.GET:
    for object in slice(object_list, 22):
        #No code here
else:
    for object in slice(object_list, 10):
        #No code here
```

which obviously is an error.

Answer (score 0):

Just close the for loop inside each conditional:

```
{% if 'latest' in request.GET %}
    {% for object in object_list|slice:"22" %}
        {{ object.name }}
    {% endfor %}

{% else %}
    {% for object in object_list|slice:"10" %}
        {{ object.name }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```